# Is it ever appropriate to use "where" instead of "because" or "since"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, differences

I work at a large company (4,000+ employees) where a lot of people use the word "where" in a way that I firmly believe is incorrect. They use "where" at the beginning of a sentence instead of using "since" or "because". Here is an example from an official internal communication that went out this morning (the entire thing makes me cringe):

"We requested that all links be redirected. However, at this time, it’s not feasible. **Where** the changes are planned for Monday, July 25, we want to ensure all staff are aware."

People have also gotten into the habit of using it in conversation. For example, "Where you have not done this before, let me know if you would like me to demonstrate it for you." Or, "Where there is a lot of work on our plates right now, we have decided to take on an additional staff member."

I had never heard the term "where" used in this way before I started working here, and it really irritates me whenever I hear someone say it. Is this an acceptable use of the word?

Comment: Do these people have English as their first language?  It's certainly not idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

Merriam-Webster's New International Dictionary, Second Edition (M.W.N.I.D 2) with a copyright date of 1953 does have such a sense of the word, but it marks it as obsolete.

> 4. (Obs.) Since; considering that; inasmuch as. B. While on the other hand.

However, what I think they meant is that it means whereas, which [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/where) marks as a possible, informal interpretation of the word "where". Whereas would make considerably more sense as it can mean.

> 2. The thing being so that; considering that things are so; implying an admission of facts, sometimes followed by a different statement, and sometimes by inferences or something consequent, as in the law style, where a preamble introduces a law. — [The American Dictionary of the English Language (A.D.E.L.) by Noah Webster](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/whereas) and published in 1828

In our context it introduces consideration of the subsequently stated fact. Also worth consideration is that "as" can also be a synonym for since, according to the Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia. A definiton of "where" as "whereas" is in the [American Heritage Dictionary 5th](http://www.tfd.com/where) edition too, [yet not the fourth](https://www.wordnik.com/words/where). It's in [Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary 1913, yet not A.D.E.L.](https://1828.mshaffer.com/d/word/where), nor [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/where) or the Merriam-Webster 10th Collegiate edition from 1993, although it can be found in the 1914 [Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia](https://www.wordnik.com/words/where). It is not in most other dictionaries I can examine online and I doubt it'll be in most of my other printed sources

In consideration of those facts and that M.W.N.I.D. 2 effectively marks this usage as obsolete, that lends me to believe its a resurgence of a fad from around the early 20th century. If you want my personal opinion, it is a fad that probably should have been forgotten, because it reduces clarity by far too much for a mere savings of two letters. I am guessing if it said whereas from the beginning, there would be little to no need for the question to be asked. We probably kept the two words separated more often for that reason.

The reason whereas might mean this probably has more to do with the "as" than the where. The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia gives some further explanation in its suggested synonyms for [Since](https://www.wordnik.com/words/since):

> Synonyms Because, Since, As, Inasmuch as, For. Because (originally by cause) is strong and the most direct. Since, starting from the idea of mere sequence in time, is naturally less emphatic as to causation: its clause more often precedes the main proposition. As is still weaker, and, like since, generally brings in the reason before the main proposition: as or since the mountain will not come to Mohammed, Mohammed must go to the mountain. Inasmuch as is the most formal and emphatic, being used only to mark the express reason or condition. For follows the main proposition, and generally introduces that which is really continuative of the main proposition and of equal or nearly equal importance, the idea of giving a reason being subordinate.

No mention of where in there or even whereas. I have not heard this used too often so I am not sure why the dictionaries are starting to include where as whereas in their pages again.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ever appropriate to use “where” instead of “because” or “since”?

No. It isn't.

I have encountered the usage of *where* in place of [*under the circumstances where*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22under%20the%20circumstances%20where%22) in Singapore. I am not 100% sure whether the usage you heard in your company is just an Indian dialect, but I can confirm the usage does exist.

Grammatically speaking, the word [*where*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/where) can't be used to introduce a dependent clause as a conjunction and the saying ["where there is a will there's a way"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/where-there-s-a-will-there-s-a-way) doesn't have the same grammatical construction.

Therefore, we have to use *since*, *because* or *under the circumstances where (where is omissible)* depending on context in your example sentences.